# File doesn't exist using Download Manager

Tags: android, download, filesystems, android-download-manager, file-copying

According to this [answer](https://coderedirect.com/questions/276839/manually-add-local-file-to-the-downloads-app) it's possible to copy a local file to the download older.
After trying this out:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getContext().getSystemService(getActivity().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
if(f.exists()){
    downloadManager.addCompletedDownload("title", "descirption", true, "application/json", f.getPath(),f.length(),true);
}
```

I receive the following issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File doesn't exist: /data/data/com.example.mytestapp/files/fd92a63b-aad5-4122-a23a-743d164243a1.jpg
```

Did this feature got cancelled in the newest android versions (30-31) and I have to copy the file in another way or is something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: "Did this feature got cancelled in the newest android versions (30-31)" -- the download service has no access to that file, as of Android 10.

Comment: @CommonsWare so the only solution is to copy the file without the downloadmanager as of android 10?